# Select2 and DepDrop in dynamic form in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to use Select2 and depdrop within a dynamic form. For the first row it's working only. But on the next row I'm getting following error.
[image]

When I'm using select2 without depfrop it works fine.

Code of form (of select2 and depdrop field)

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">

                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]productname")->label(false)->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productbatch::find()->orderBy('productname')->all(),'productname','productname'),
                                    'language' => 'en',
                                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product','id' => 'prodname'],
                                    'pluginOptions' => [
                                        'allowClear' => true
                                    ],
                                    ]); 
                                ?>                                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">   
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, 'batchno')->label(false)->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                                    //'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id'],
                                    'pluginOptions'=>[
                                        'depends'=>['prodname'],
                                        'placeholder'=>'Batch No',
                                        'url'=>Url::to(['/invoice/bills/subcat'])
                                    ]
                                    ]); ?>
```

Code of subcat action

```
public function actionSubcat() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            $out = Productbatch::getBatchNo($cat_id);
            echo Json::encode($out);
            // the getSubCatList function will query the database based on the
            // cat_id and return an array like below:
            // [
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
            // ]
            //echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if anymore input from my end is required.

Answer (score 1):

check your codes to find JavaScript codes for the first element that works correctly.you should be add JavaScript codes for all same elements that produces by insert button.
 I suggest you to extended another dynamic form from `\wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget` for your own.Then override `registerAssets` function and add  JavaScripts for other  insert handler.

Comment: Did you got any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

It has problem is yii2-dynamic-form.js file of dynamic form. Same solution work for Select2 and DepDrop both.

solution on following link works for me.

[https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/issues/76#top[Updated](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/issues/76#top%5BUpdated) Code][1]