# DynamicForm + javascript

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamic-forms

I have some dynamic forms working in `Yii2` and it works fine for me, but I need to add a little function to get cost price and sale price. It is work in the first dynamic form but the other one it dose not.

My Form code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
         <?= $form->field($modelPoItem, "[{$i}]po_item_no")->dropDownList(
                            arrayhelper::map(Itemes::find()->all(),'itemes_id','item_name'),
                            ['prompt'=>'select Item', 'onchange' => 'getProduct($(this))', 'onkeyup' => 'getProduct($(this))']
                            ) ?>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
          <?= $form->field($modelPoItem, "[{$i}]quantity")->textInput(['maxlength' => 128 ])  ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?= $form->field($modelPoItem, "[{$i}]cost_price")->textInput(['maxlength' => 128]) ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <?= $form->field($modelPoItem, "[{$i}]sale_price")->textInput(['maxlength' => 128]) ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS code :

```
function getProduct(item) {
 var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
 var itemes_id =$('#poitem-'+index+'-po_item_no').val();
 $.get('index.php?r=itemes/price',{ itemes_id : itemes_id },function(data)
  {
   var data=$.parseJSON(data);
   alert('#poitem-'+index+'-sale_price'); // i used it just to check if the id Is correct 
   $('#poitem-'+index+'-sale_price').attr('value',data.sale_price);
   $('#poitem-'+index+'-cost_price').attr('value',data.cost_price);
  });
}
```

[image: Update - 1]

[image: Update - 2]

[image: Update - 3]

Comment: it is not very clear what is the problem. do you have error messages of some sort? "it does not work" is not very helpful

Comment: @Elzo Valugi i updated my  question Sir !

Comment: Isn't this id: $('#poitem-0-po_item_no') for only 1st form that you generate? You should have a common class in all forms in order to run your javascript code.

Comment: @Chinmay yes it is .

Comment: You can use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164600/yii2-dynamicforms-and-javascript/40192192#40192192)

Comment: @InsaneSkull I Don't get it ..  i tried it but it gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: getProduct is not defined`

Comment: It's same thing you are trying..just get respective index and make id using it dynamically. `var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");` use this at `$('#poitem-index here-cost_price').attr('value',data.cost_price);`. Make simple js function and call onchange. Problem with your registerJs?

Comment: for solving this problem I extended default dynamic form widget and add jquery codes in this function :$('.dynamicform_wrapper').on('afterInsert', function(e, item) {}

Comment: view the answer of this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457408/select2-and-depdrop-in-dynamic-form-in-yii2 .It helps to you too.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I've update my JS code ..but it still not working .. can you check it please

Comment: Remove `$('#poitem-'+index+'-po_item_no').change(function() {}` from js, not needed anymore.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Not work too ..  and i update my qustion

Comment: i will make a demo for you..when i get time.

Comment: @InsaneSkull i've changed    `$('#poitem-'+index+'-sale_price').attr('value',55);` and test it .. the first dynamic form but the other one it dose not... so is there any problem my assets Files ? i will add pic of my assets file !

Comment: no problem with assets.

Comment: Change `$('#poitem-'+index+'-sale_price').attr('value',data.sale_price);` to `$('#poitem-'+index+'-sale_price').val(data.sale_price);`

Comment: @InsaneSkull You Are not Insane you are  genius .. its work ! thank you

Comment: buddy i am insane that's why i am genius. :). Glad helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getProduct(item) {
   var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
   var itemes_id =$('#poitem-'+index+'-po_item_no').val();
   $.get('index.php?r=itemes/price',{ itemes_id : itemes_id },function(data)
   {
      var data=$.parseJSON(data);

     $('#poitem-'+index+'-sale_price').val(data.sale_price);
     $('#poitem-'+index+'-cost_price').val(data.cost_price);
   });
}
```